# Android Emulator resolution not proper with GPU emulation

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit on a machine which has ATI Radeon 6550M as the GPU. I have installed the proprietary driver(1) from the AMD website. OpenGL rendering works fine with the driver.

I have installed an android emulator with and AVD (4.0.3) running x86 arch with help from the TestObject blog(2). I have also enabled KVM support, and it works almost fine. I also have another AVD under ARM architecture. There is a small issue with both these AVDs.

When I run the emulator (either x86 or ARM) with GPU emulation (option "-gpu on"), the resolution of the emulator is horrible. This happens only with the GPU emulation set, not otherwise.

With GPU emulation:
[image: Android Emulator with GPU Emulation]

Without GPU emulation:
[image: Android Emulator without GPU Emulation]

As you can wsee, the display with GPU emulation is horrible. Why is it so? How do I see the issue and work around the same?

(1) http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx
(2) http://blog.testobject.org/2012/04/giving-your-android-emulator-boost.html

Thanks and Regards,
Hrishikesh Murali

Comment: I have the same issue on my mid-2011 macbook air with Intel HD Graphics 3000.